# centos csh unset environmental variable

Tags: environment-variables, centos6, csh

Recently, I set a environmental variable in the .cshrc file in CentOS 6.6 system, with the command `setenv CXX g++-4.8.5/bin/g++`. Afterwards, I don't want to this CXX being set any more. So I comment out this line. However, when I launch a new terminal (right click and select Konsole in the main screen), this CXX still is set to g++-4.8.5/bin/g++.

Does anyone know what's going there?

Thank you.

Comment: either there is another `.` file that is being sourced that also includes that value for `CXX` (look at your `man csh`, search for `.cshrc` and see what other "startup files" are scanned) OR you there is some problem with your `.cshrc` file that is causing the `#` to be ignored (unlikely) OR tell us how you "launch(ed) a new terminal", as certain use cases would inherit values in the launching environment (Please edit your Q, rather than respond in comments on this). Good luck.

Comment: My best guess is that `$CXX` is still set in your current shell, and when you launched a new terminal from that shell it inherited it. Commenting out a line in `.cshrc` doesn't affect the environment of any running process. To remove it in your current shell, `unsetenv CXX`

Comment: I understand using `unsetenv CXX` in the current shell. I want to CXX is not set when I launch a new shell not from the existing shell.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your machine completely? If so and you're still having trouble, then the first item I mentioned is likely the culprit. Good luck.

Comment: No, I haven't reboot the machine. I don't have the authority. Maybe reboot will solve the problem. Thank you.